# Custom Query for wp_posts using wp_postmeta

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

In postmeta lets say

> 1. meta_key = 'count' and meta_value = '5'
> 2. meta_key = 'count' and meta_value = '6'
> 3. meta_key = 'count' and meta_value = '7'

now i want to get all post

```
WHERE meta_key = 'count'

AND orderby = 'meta_value_num'

AND order by ASC
```

**NOTE: I dont wanna use query_posts or wp_query. just custom sql query.
Thanks in advance.**

Comment: why don't you put all you said,in a query and try?

Comment: What's wrong with `wp_query()`? :S

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT wposts.*, postmeta.*
FROM wp_posts as wposts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as postmeta ON (postmeta.post_id = wposts.ID)
WHERE wposts.post_type = 'post'
AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND postmeta.meta_key = 'count'
ORDER BY postmeta.meta_value ASC
```

Here `wp_` is the prefix of database table, you can replace it with your own db table prefix.